# Where to find Authentication method used by an email client on Exchange 2016 onpremises?

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, bearer-token, exchange-server-2016

digging into the logging folder on the exchange installation I found the folder

E:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi

where I could find authentication events related to Outlook 2010 (Negotiate) and Outlook 2016 (Bearer).

But I cannot find the related authentication events from any other clients such as the Windows Mail client, Outlook mobile app or Mac clients. Does someone know where I could find those?

Many thanks.